# Why does React have to use setState for state update?

Tags: reactjs

Why does react have to update state (tree reconciliation) using setState. And not by simply initializing this.state.color = 'red'; supposing that previous value for color is 'green'.

Comment: Read [Why Not To Modify React State Directly](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how React is built.

The concept is that you should not change the state mutably, like this:

```
this.state.color = 'red';
```

Instead, you should use setState:

```
this.setState({color: 'red'});
```

The idea behind that is that in order to track changes in state and than re-render the component according to the changes, you have to use setState, because after setState, the render function is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `this.state.color = 'red';` you mutate the state, it will not trigger re-render.

`this.setState({color: 'red'})` will create a new state and assign it to `this.state` changing it in an immutable way, thus React will know it has changed and will re-render the component.

It's down to how JavaScript works, all primitive values (number, string, boolean, undefined, null) are copied by value when you type `let age = 34` or something similar.

But objects and arrays are copied by reference.
You can read more about it here: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2):

The use of `this.state.color = 'red'` will not trigger a re-render, while `this.setState({ color: 'red })` will. There are other things to consider.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question is *why* this happens, not if.

Comment: The question is why use one and not the other. One triggers a re-render and doesn't mutate the state directly, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Another imp reason is using setState returns a new state and does not mutate the original state, which can be passed to a pure component. Since pure component only does shallow rendering of objects if the new state is not returned the component will not re render.

Answer (score 1):

React JS is single way binding so state variable could be changed on setState only so it renders once setState in set.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` function has internal access to the behavior of its top-level function that is defined in it. it's not magic just use `this` reference.

So by calling `setState` function, it takes its higher level function and uses `this` for `DOM` comparison.

simple example create `useState` :)

```js
function createState(val) {
    // `this` is top level reference (App function)
    const state = {
        call: 0,
        context: this,
        value: val
    };

    var _useState = function(callback){
        
         val = state.value = callback(val);
         
         state.call++;
         console.log("call: ", state.call)

         return val
    };

    return _useState;
};

function useState(value) {
  return [
       value,
       // pass null to access parent reference (App function)
       createState.bind(null, value)()
  ]; 
}

function App() {
    
  const  [val, setVal] =  useState(10)

  console.log(setVal(v => v+3));
  console.log(setVal(v => v+3));

}

App()
```